# How can I become sub-30 speedcuber?

Tags: rubiks-cube

I am young speedcuber (in primary school) and I use Fridrich to solve a cube. I know all 21 PLL algorithms and 7 OLL. My best is 28 sec and average is 39 sec. Do you have any tips that can help me become a sub-30 cuber?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! When you say you're in primary school, you mean you're under-13, right? Because if you are, I'm afraid you're violating the site's [terms and conditions](https://stackexchange.com/legal) - you need to be 13 or over to have a StackExchange account (16 or over if you're in the EU, apparently).

Comment: No. I'm not under 13. I'm exactly 13.

Comment: In that case, welcome! [This previous question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11492/how-do-i-become-a-sub-30-cuber?rq=1) may be of interest to you.